# send parameters to a aspx page from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to be able to send parameters to an ASPX.cs page from a mvc controller. the parameters are all strings so i was trying to use redirect but it is not taking me to aspx page. Any ideas?

```
public void generateReport(string one, string 2)
{ //some code......
    Response.Redirect(string.Concat("~/Reporting/Viewer.aspx?", "ReportName=", ReportName, "&procedureName=", procedure, "&delimParms=", stringParms, "&delimitor=", delim));
}
```

Comment: Where is it taking you? You should provide an example of the URL you expect to end up at the an example of the URL you actually end up at.

Comment: "string 2" - really?

Comment: @Igor hehehe :D maybe a pseudo code! :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're doing it well. Since you don't have any idea that you're working on. I would try to mock you and give you one.

Have a look at the following code,

```
Session["param1"] = "Value of the first param.";
Session["param2"] = "Value of the second param.";
```

..these are called session parameters. They are sent to the client, throughout the session of his, on your website. You can create as many session variables as you want and they get removed when the users leaves your website.

You can use these, to pass on the strings from your server down to the user. This way you can minimize the code of your application, and just create a new session variable on the server, and call it on the page where you want to use it.

### Example Code

For example assume a page called CreateString and then call the variables on the second page.

#### `CreateString`

The following code,

```
Session["ReportName"] = "Some Name";
Session["procudureName"] = "Procedure Name";
Session["delimParms"] = "bla bla";
Session["delimitor"] = "bla bla";
```

#### Get it on second page

On the second page you can recall these variables, using the following code

```
if(Session["ReportName"] != null) {
   // make sure it is not null, and is created and has value
   string ReportName = Session["ReportName"];
}
```

..you can continue your work all the way down to the variable that you had to pass down the stream.

#### Note

Long URLs are not good UX. Some browsers also limit the usage of the characters in the URL so your data might be not happy inside the URL, create a session variable and pass it. It will be available to the user only and only when he is using the website (inside the session only).